# Can no longer boot into Ubuntu after re-installing Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 16.04, windows-10

I started out with a Windows machine and installed Ubuntu to dualboot. It had issues with throwing me into emergency mode but after disabling hibernation and fast startup on windows, I could use it.

Yesterday, I re-installed Windows 10 while keeping the Ubuntu install and it gave me the emergency mode again when trying to boot into Ubuntu. After disabling hibernation and fast startup, it still does not boot.

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!

The issue was in `/etc/fstab`, it was trying to mount my Windows partition and it was failing for some reason.

Commenting the windows partition out fixed it for me.

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Comment: @DavidFoerster How can I elaborate? One just has to open `/etc/fstab` any way they like and the windows partition would jump at them.

Comment: How does one open `/etc/fstab` when only a super-user has write privileges? How does one identify the right entry? How can one turn it into a comment? Just because it seems trivial to you, doesn't id does to most people.